# Is the product of Lindlar hydrogenation of (2Z,4S)-4-methylhept-2-en-5-yne optically active?

Tags: organic-chemistry, redox, stereochemistry, chirality

According to me the poisoned catalyst will only reduce the triple bond so the compound produced must be optically active.. But the answer given is that the final product is optically inactive.. is it correct and if so how?

[image: (2Z,4S)-4-methylhept-2-en-5-yne]

this is the final product I made:

[image: (2Z,5Z)-4-methylhepta-2,5-diene]

The triple bond gets reduced to double bond as Lindlar's catalyst has been used so the reduction stops at this stage.. is this correct?

Comment: What do you think you get when you reduce the triple bond? Have you drawn the structure?

Comment: I have posted the structure I made.. Please check it @matt

Comment: And is this optically active? Does it have a carbon with 4 distinct units attached?

Comment: sorry.. I overlooked the 2 group[s are same.. Thanks.. i understood..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The two *cis*-configured pro-1-en-1-yl groups present on the central carbon remove the asymmetry. You can put a plane of symmetry through the $\ce{Me-C-H}$ plane of the central carbon to transform the molecule onto itself. You can confirm that by rotating the $\ce{(C=)C-C(HMeR)}$ bond.

Thus, this hydrogenation removes chirality.