# Why does hydrogenation of this compound not result in a diastereomeric mixture?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, symmetry, organic-reduction, cis-trans-isomerism

In a question, this compound was given and it was asked:

"Hydrogenation of the above compound in the presence of poisoned Palladium catalyst gives?"

[image: reactant]

When I was answering it, I thought that the Lindlar catalyst would partially reduce the alkyne to give a cis alkene which would create two compounds that look like this:

[image: products]

Clearly, compound I is optically inactive due to the presence of plane of symmetry but compound II does not have any such plane of symmetry so it must be optically active. Hence, I answered that the resulting product would be a diastereomeric mixture since I and II are diastereomers wrt each other.

But, the solution to the question suggests that only compound I forms, with no explanation given for why compound II does not form. Searching on the net was also of no help. Could someone provide an explanation?

Thanks for your time and apologies for the sloppy drawings.

Comment: [Is the product of Lindlar hydrogenation of (2Z,4S)-4-methylhept-2-en-5-yne optically active?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/68346/is-the-product-of-lindlar-hydrogenation-of-2z-4s-4-methylhept-2-en-5-yne-optic)

Comment: Thank you. I have understood the answer. I had not been able to find a solution of this problem when I had searched about it previously.

Comment: No prob, let's close this as a duplicate then. Nice drawings by the way, no need to be sorry.